# Bitbake do_rootfs failure for syslog-ng

Tags: yocto, bitbake, syslog-ng

I am using syslog-ng from meta-oe: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/1030/. I have set my bblayers file accordingly. To include syslog-ng in my root image, I add a change to my build/conf/local.conf file:

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "syslog-ng"
```

To build my image, I do: **bitbake core-image-full-cmdline**

But, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
pacakgegroup-core-full-cmdline : Depends: packagegroup-core-full-cmdline-initscripts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I get the same error if I replace *CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL* with:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "syslog-ng"
```

Comment: Do you have any problem if you don't install `syslog-ng` ?

Comment: `syslog-ng` has `RCONFLICTS_${PN} = "busybox-syslog sysklogd rsyslog"`, maybe you need to remove those packages from `core-image-full-cmdline` ?

Comment: @Nayfe How can I remove those packages?

Comment: IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "<package>"

Comment: @Nayfe Still, I get same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, yocto uses syslogd if an alternative is not provided. This link https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-March/040327.html posts similar kind of error. Considering that and the case with syslogkg, I made the following changes to my local.conf file:

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"

VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog = "syslog-ng"

DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
```

I have not properly tested these changes with *package_deb*. But, the above configuration does the work.